# Retain Cell Selection After View has Changed

Tags: swift

I currently have a navigation controller in my project.

The user is presented with 3 tables, one at a time, within which they can select some options.

My issue is that if a user makes a mistake and wants to go back to the previous table, the option they chose is no longer selected. This causes them to select it again - which creates duplicates in an array that stores data.

How can I have the table retain the selection so that if the user goes back to the previous table the option remains selected?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `UITableViewController` for your tables?

From Apple's documentation:

> In -viewWillAppear:, it reloads the table's data if it's empty.
>   Otherwise, it deselects all rows (with or without animation) if
>   clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear is YES.

So probably you will need to just set `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to `false` on your view controllers and hopefully everything will work as expected.